# Custom Django url for users

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-login

Hi I have been trying to create customer url for my users but it does not work. I keep getting NoReverseMatchError

This is my user_login views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    '''
    Using different method for getting username, tried this and didnt work either
    '''
    #if request.user.is_authenticated():
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('main:home')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:              
                login(request,user)
                messages.info(request, "Successfully signed in")
                return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main:home', kwargs={'username': username})) 
            else:
                message = 'Sorry, the username or password you entered is not valid please try again.'
                return render(request, 'login.html', {'message':message})
        else:
            message = 'Sorry, the username or password you entered is not valid please try again.'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'message':message})
```

This is my form for login at login.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{%url 'main:home' user.username %}" class="form-signin">
```

This is my view "home"

```
def home(request, username):
    username = request.user.get_username()
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

This is my url path at myapp/urls.py

```
path('home/<username>', views.home, name='home'),
```

This is the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/main/home'
```

I am trying to get mysite.com/home/myusername, but it is giving me a NoReverseMarch error

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /main/
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['main/home/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you try rendering the value of `user.username` and check that its not an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), you can not use such `path(..)`s, and in that case you need to **write a regular expression**, like:

```
    url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

If you are using [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), you probably want to use **`path(..)`**, like you have.

I believe it may be to do with how you've set up your regex.

For urls, instead of this:

`url('complete/<todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),`

try this:

```
url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>\d+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Or incase you want to use [`path`]

```
path('complete/<int:todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using slug for the user names.. Because when the user name has space in between the words the URL breaks into two. Slug will replace space with -.

for example user name is John Mathew , django will search for `home/john` instead of `home/john mathew` . if you use slug for user name it will send the user name like this `home/john-mathew`....Try that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` and the URLs you have created.

as per the

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/main/home'
```

after login, the user is redirected to `/main/home`.
Unfortunately, no such path exists in your URLs declaration.
Instead, your "home" URL in urls.py has an additional parameter `username` which is not found by `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, thus the error occurs.

remove the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` from the settings.py and it should work as you desire.